# Showing multiple Partialviews error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm pretty new to MVC and its partial views, I made a Viewmodel class:

```
 public class CategoryBlogPost
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Blogpost> Blogpost { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller I created this:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CategoryBlogpost model = new CategoryBlogpost
            {
                Blogpost = new List<Blogpost>(),
                Category = new List<Category>()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

I've made two partial views; _BlogpostPartial and _CategoryPartial:

**_BlogpostPartial:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Blogpost>

   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
              <h3> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject)</h3>
              <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Detail)</p>
    }
```

**_CategoryPartial:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Category>

<form>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "GetBlogpostsByCat", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID) })
    }
</form>
```

and this is my Page where I call them:

```
@model Project.Models.CategoryBlogpost

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.Partial("_BlogpostPartial", Model.Blogpost)


@Html.Partial("_CategoryPartial", Model.Category)
```

This returns a page with both my views, but without any output from the foreach statements
This is because I never used my `getAllBlogposts()` , I've made this method, but I have no idea where to put it now. Usually I just put it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(BlogpostRepository.getAllBlogposts);
}
```

but as you can see, this method isn't possible now

Comment: `BlogPost` is an object, not a collection. Are you wanting to display a collection of `BlogPost` or does `BlogPost` have a property which is a collection and you want to display that?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'd like to display a collection of blogposts, of which the subject and other details are within my Blogpost.cs class
I already have a getAllBlogposts() method in my BlogpostRepository but I have no Idea how to use it in a _partial view_, it easily shows them in a regular view with Blogpost as Model, and the same goes for `Category`

Comment: Your model `CategoryBlogPost` and has property `Blogpost Blogpost { get; set; }`. It should be `IEnumerable<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }` if you want to display a collection of BlogPost's

Comment: Okay, thank you, I made some changes and it compiles now! But It doesn't load my Blogposts, Where do I need to put the getAllBlogposts()?
Usually I put it in the `return View(BPRepository.getAllBlogposts())`, but now it's filled with the model, as you can see in in my code

Comment: Not enough room here. I'll post answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are wanting to display a collection of `Blogpost` and `Category`, your view model should be

```
public class CategoryBlogPost
{
  public IEnumerable<Blogpost> Blogposts { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Then in you index method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  CategoryBlogpost model = new CategoryBlogpost();
  // Populate collections
  model.Blogposts = BPRepository.getAllBlogposts();
  model.Categories = ....

  return View(model);
}
```

Note I used plural of property names, so this may impact in your view

Answer (score 0):

Just correct your

`@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Blogpost>`

as

`@model Project.Models.Blogpost`

and

`@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Category>`

as

`@model Project.Models.Category`

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Project.Models.Blogpost' because 'Project.Models.Blogpost' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @user3208179...you are using foreach loop wrongly in partialview.. you cannot use foreach on Model..

Comment: I'm not using it on Model I'm using it for each item in Model, which usually works perfectly when not in a partialview